# Lua Scripting error with G-Key script SetMkeyState

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I have a G602 mouse and I want to use the DPI sensitive buttons (G10, G11) to control the M-Key state of my G910 keyboard.  I'm trying to write a Lua script for it, but I'm having problems trying to set the M-Key state based off the API documentation sample:

```
if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 11 then
    SetMkeyState(1,"kb")
end
```

I get the following error:

```
[string "LuaVM"]:20: attempt to call global 'SetMkeyState' (a nil value)
```

I even tried the exact sample from the API documentation and I get the same error:

```
-- Set the current M Key state to M1 when G1 is pressed
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 1) then
        SetMkeyState(1);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is case-sensitive and the sample in API Documentation has a typo.  The letter K in `SetMkeyState` should be upper-case.

Using `SetMKeyState` works:

```
if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 11 then
    SetMKeyState(1,"kb")
end
```